# How can I add searched multiple addresses to UISearchBar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uisearchbar

[image]

How can i this thing achieved in iOS ?

till now i did the below code 
enter image description here

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How did you save these values into array?

Comment: Please explain some more details

Comment: its a screenshot from web portal and I''ll be saving these values into array through webservice ?

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: I am able to display all the below addresses in tableview below uisearchbar and when I select it should display in uisearchbar

Comment: @VickyiOS - simple ,create one array add details

Comment: @VickyiOS - are you tried my answer

Comment: see i have added the screen in the above